# Entity Framework Core model with hierarchy of the same table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I use an ASP.NET Core Web API with .NET 5 and Entity Framework Core 5.

I have a table called `Article` with some properties, and I am struggling that the article could contain other articles. Like a hierarchy or some kind of "Bill of Materials".

I do not want to create extra tables like `SubArticle` because it could be nested multiple times.

I thought about of creating a mapping table `ArticleHierarchy` that is also used for M2M relations but with only one table, is this possible?

```
public class Article
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }        
    public string SomeProperties { get; set; } 

    public virtual ICollection<ArticleHierarchy> ArticleHierarchies { get; set; }           
}

public class ArticleHierarchy
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(ParentArticle))]
    public int ArticleParentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(ChildArticle))]
    public int ArticleChildId { get; set; }

    public virtual Article ParentArticle { get; set; }
    public virtual Article ChildArticle { get; set; }
}
```

Is this a way to go, and if so, how do my classes need to look like?

Or is there even a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to fix relations, add

```
public class Article
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }        
    public string SomeProperties { get; set; } 


    [InverseProperty(nameof(ArticleHierarchy.ChildArticle))]
    public virtual ICollection<ArticleHierarchy> ChildArticleHierarchies { get; set; }    

    [InverseProperty(nameof(ArticleHierarchy.ParentArticle))]
     public virtual ICollection<ArticleHierarchy> ParentArticleHierarchies { get; set;}
       
}

public class ArticleHierarchy
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
   
    public int ArticleParentId { get; set; }
 
    public int ArticleChildId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ParentArticleId))]
    [InverseProperty("ParentArticleHierarchies")]
    public virtual Article ParentArticle { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ChildArticleId))]
    [InverseProperty("ChildArticleHierarchies")]
    public virtual Article ChildArticle { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I needed to add `modelBuilder.Entity<ArticleHierarchy>()
            .HasKey(e => new { e.ArticleChildId, e.ArticleParentId });` because I got an error when I run the migration. Now the Migration runs, but when I run the "update-database" I get the following error: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_ArticleHierarchy_Article_ArticleParentId' on table 'ArticleHierarchy' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors

Comment: @AnNormalie Remove modelBuilder.Entity<ArticleHierarchy>()   .HasKey(e => new { e.ArticleChildId, e.ArticleParentId }) and make Id as a key, see my answer.

Comment: this worked to remove the migration error withou the need of FluentApi Code. But I still get the error when I run the update-database. I got it fixed using `modelBuilder.Entity<Article>()
 .HasMany(e => e.ParentArticleHierarchies)
 .WithOne(e => e.ParentArticle)
 .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

modelBuilder.Entity<Article>()
 .HasMany(e => e.ChildArticleHierarchies)
 .WithOne(e => e.ChildArticle)
 .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);`